# How to profile map reduce jobs on HBase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a map reduce job which runs over a HBase table. It scans the Hbase table after applying some scan filters and does some processing.

The job is taking long time, definitely much more than expected and feels like the performance deterioration is exponential (i.e, the first 90% completes much faster than the rest and after about 98% (of the mappers complete), seems like getting stuck in eternity like the limbo in the movie inception.

From high level there should be no reason for this uneven performance since each row in the scan is expected to behave similarly and the downstream service should have similar SLAs every row of the HBase table.

How do I debug and profile this job? Are there any tools available out there which would help me meter the system and pinpoint the misbehaving component?

Comment: The "uneven" performance is a characteristic of map-reduce itself.  Since it starts everything in parallel and some tasks finish sooner than others, throughput is initially very high and dwindles as time goes on.

Comment: Are there tools to analyze where time is being spent and the breakup?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to monitor and debug jobs like this.

The first is to look at logs for the RegionServers, Datanodes, and TaskTrackers and try to find any error messages.  The JobTracker will also contain a breakdown of performance per task, you can look to see if any tasks are failing or getting killed along with messages as to why.  That's the easiest most straightforward place to start

In my experience, slow MapReduce jobs with HBase indicate uneven key distributions across your regions.  For TableInputFormats, the default split is a mapper per region, if one of your regions contains an uneven number of rows you are accessing or if a particular RegionServer has several regions that are being read by several mappers, that could cause slowdowns on the machine because of disk contention or network io.

For debugging the RegionServers, you can take a look at [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/whatsnew8.html)  this is mentioned in the [HBase Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase) as the profiler they use.  I've never used it, but it does have a probe for HBase.  Standard CPU load via `uptime` or `top` and IO wait from `iostat` metrics would also allow you to identify which machines are slowing things down.

If you don't want to run a profiling tool, you could monitor the RegionServer WebUI and look to see if you have a lot of RPC requests queued up or if they are taking a long time, this is available is an easily parseable JSON format.  That would allow you to pinpoint slowdowns for particular regions that your job is processing.

Network IO could also be a contributing factor.  If you are running a MapReduce cluster separate from the HBase cluster, then all of the data has to be shipped to the TaskTrackers, so that may be saturating your network.  Standard network monitoring tools could be used.

Another problem could simply be with the Scanner itself, turning on cacheblocks generally hurts performance during MR jobs in my experience.  This is because of a high level of cache churn as you are generally only reading rows once during MR jobs.  Also, filters attached to Scanners are applied server side, so if you are doing complex filtering that may cause higher latency.